# Slow query using MongoDB and PHP

Tags: php, performance, mongodb, mlab

I have two collections. The first one, $bluescan, has 345 documents and some ['company'] values missing. The second one, $maclistResults, has 20285 documents.

I'm running $bluescan against $maclistResults to fill missing ['company'] values.

I created three indexes for $maclistResults using the following PHP code:

```
$db->$jsonCollectionName->ensureIndex(array('mac' => 1));
$db->$jsonCollectionName->ensureIndex(array('company' => 1));
$db->$jsonCollectionName->ensureIndex(array('mac'=>1, 'company'=>1));
```

I'm using a MongoLab free account for the DB and running my PHP application locally.

The code below demonstrates the process. It works, does what I need but it takes almost 64 seconds to perform the task.

Is there anything I can do to improve this execution time?

Code:

```
else
{
  $maclist = 'maclist';
  $time_start = microtime(true);
  foreach ($bluescan as $key => $value)
  {
    $maclistResults = $db->$maclist->find(array('mac'=>substr($value['mac'], 0, 8)), array('mac'=>1, 'company'=>1));
    foreach ($maclistResults as $value2) 
    {
      if (empty($value['company']))
      {
        $bluescan[$key]['company'] = $value2['company'];
      }
    }
  }
}
$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = $time_end - $time_start;
echo "<pre>";
echo "maclistResults execution time: ".$time." seconds";
echo "</pre>";
```

Echo output from $time:

```
maclistResults execution time: 63.7298750877 seconds
```

Additional info: PHP version 5.6.2 (MAMP PRO on OSX Yosemite)

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, each `find` operation you perform in your `foreach` loop results in a call to the server, meaning 345 calls to the server, plus whatever operation you perform on `$bluescan` previously. Just the overhead of the network could kill your program's performance... Just take a look at the individual execution times for these `find` call.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by SolarBear, you're actually executing find as often as you have elements in $bluescan.

You should first fetch the list from the server and the iterate over that result set instead, basically exactly the opposite order of your current code.